# Pass string value as object to Redux component with PropTypes in React

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-redux, redux-form, react-final-form

A component using [Redux example](https://codesandbox.io/s/4xq2qpzw79) from [React Final Form](https://github.com/final-form/react-final-form) was created in  `index.js`.

`<FormStateFromRedux valueName="valueString" form="counter" />`

It is using redux to track values, using `prop-types` it should receive object name to return exact object value:

```
const FormStateFromRedux = ({ state, valueName }) => (
  <p>{state.values.valueName}</p>
)

export default connect((state, ownProps) => ({
  state: getFormState(state, ownProps.form)
}))(FormStateFromRedux)

 FormStateFromRedux.propTypes = {
  valueName: PropTypes.objectOf(PropTypes.string)
};
```

It is possible to return value when object path is set manually, here I want to make reusable component to return values using PropTypes but don't know what kind of type to choose. Is it possible to pass value as string? May someone know what should be correct approach in this case?

**UPDATE**

It is possible to get string value inside object using `[]`

`const FormStateFromRedux = ({ state, valueName }) => (
      <p>{state.values[valueName]}</p>
    )`

Answer (score 1):

You should avoid passing whole form state to component. Component should have only necessary props.

```
const FormStateFromRedux = ({ valueName }) => ( <p>{valueName}</p> );

export default connect((state, props) => {
  const formState = getFormState(state, props.form);
  const { value : { valueName } } = formState;
  return { valueName };
})(FormStateFromRedux);

FormStateFromRedux.propTypes = {
  valueName: PropTypes.string
};
```

Comment: Many thanks for your help, I tried you solution but got error: `Module build failed: /src/Components/FormStateFromRedux.js: Duplicate declaration "state"` May you know where the problem could be?

Comment: My bad.
I have updated the solution.
Please let me know if it works now

Comment: Changed ` const { value : { valueName } } = formState;` to ` const { valueS : { valueName } } = formState;` to compile it. Still it returns empty `<p></p>` to DOM

Comment: Please try adding console.log() for value and valueName before returning it as prop. You can also try printing state, so that you will get to know what is missing.

Comment: Seems that `valueName` is returned as `undefined`.

Comment: There you go. value seems to be not containing valueName. Log the value and get the correct key which you want to get to DOM under <p> tag. :)

Comment: Already tried `const result = formState.values.valueName=this.props;` and `const { values : { valueName = this.props} } = formState;` but still getin `undefined`

Comment: Seems that const `{ values : { [${'string'}]:val } } = formState;` returns value but when `"String"` part is changed with `valueName` it returns error: `'valueName' is not defined no-undef`. Also `const FormStateFromRedux = ({ valueName }) => ( <p>{valueName}</p> );` prints string input from `index.js` when it is not used in `export default connect((state, props) => {...})`